# Linux driver - How to prevent interrupt

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am new to linux driver and  writing a char driver for hardware.

What is the exact way to prevent interrupt(software/hardware) jamming in while the driver functions (eg. ioctl) is executing?

Thanks,

Pui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean disabling all interrupts in the system ? That is not actually not a good idea.

If you have a section of code and you want to make sure that an unexpected interrupt doesn't come in the way, have a look at spin_lock_irqsave(). This will disable interrupts locally. When you are done, you can then use spin_lock_irqrestore().

If you are concerned about only updating a variable, you might consider making it atomic(atomic_t).

Lastly, if you are only thinking of disabling interrupts from your char hardware when the driver is executing a certain kind of function, that will be hardware dependent. For example, for the [LSI 1068E](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35.4/drivers/message/fusion/mptbase.c#L8379), you have to write 0xFFFFFFFF to the IntMask register. You can also ask the kernel to disable an interrupt line by using disable_irq() on that interrupt line but that is not probably what you want.